# Using invert range in sed

Tags: sed

I have this:

```
$ cat f2
123-foo-456
abc-xx
foo-yy
ddd-ao
abc
6778
123
```

This gives me: (#1)

```
$ sed -n -e '/456/,/ddd/{/ddd/{!s/a/A/g;!s/o/Q/g};p}'  f2
123-foo-456
abc-xx
foo-yy
ddd-ao
```

And this gives me: (#2)

```
$ sed -n -e '/456/,/ddd/{/ddd/!{s/a/A/g;s/o/Q/g};p}'  f2
123-fQQ-456
Abc-xx
fQQ-yy
ddd-ao
```

I prefer #2 since it does what I wanted to get as output.

Can someone explain the difference between the two? 
And a good source of documentation that explains the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no noteworthy difference between the 2. They are both unintelligible sequences of random characters that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and so should never be used. sed is for simple substitution on individual lines, that is all. If you're using more than s, g, and p (with -n) then you're using the wrong tool. Stop wasting your time on this and just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/456/ { f=1 }
f {
    if (/ddd/) {
        f=0
    }
    else {
        gsub(/a/,"A")
        gsub(/o/,"Q")
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
123-fQQ-456
Abc-xx
fQQ-yy
ddd-ao
```

Clear, simple, concise, robust, efficient, portable and better in every other way than an equivalent sed solution.

Or if having everything squeezed onto one line is appealing to you:

```
$ awk '/456/{f=1}f{if(/ddd/)f=0;else{gsub(/a/,"A");gsub(/o/,"Q")}print}' file
123-fQQ-456
Abc-xx
fQQ-yy
ddd-ao
```

You COULD write the awk script in the same style as the sed script:

```
$ awk '/456/,/ddd/{if(!/ddd/){gsub(/a/,"A");gsub(/o/,"Q")}print}' file
123-fQQ-456
Abc-xx
fQQ-yy
ddd-ao
```

but then you get the duplicated conditions (`/ddd/` twice) that come with using range expressions which is one reason why they should never be used. Fortunately, unlike sed, awk has variables and so you never need to write range expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
/ddd/{!s/a/A/g;!s/o/Q/g}
```

- when `ddd` is on the line (working buffer)

  - execute sub code `{ ...}`
  - never (`!`) address ( with empty adress it mean every line so on no lines) substitute (`s/a/A/g`) ...

So it do nothing

`/ddd/!{s/a/A/g;s/o/Q/g}`

- when `ddd` is **NOT** on the line (working buffer) (`!` is for address/pattern `/ddd/`)

  - execute sub code `{ ...}`
  - substitue (`s/a/A/g`), ...

It change `a` to `A` on line  that does not contain `ddd`

Comment: Sed has a little used translate command `y` perhaps `/ddd/!y/ao/AQ/` would be clearer. An alternative solution would be `sed '/456/!d;:a;y/ao/AQ/;n;/ddd/!ba'  file`.